# ADAL.NET - why is AcquireTokenAsync needed when authenticating OnBehalfOf from an API to an API?

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory, adal

The canonical pattern for getting access tokens using ADAL.NET looks like this:

```
try
{
 result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(graphResourceId, clientId);
}
catch (AdalException adalException) 
{
 if (adalException.ErrorCode == AdalError.FailedToAcquireTokenSilently || adalException.ErrorCode == AdalError.UserInteractionRequired)
 {
  result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId,
                                               clientCred, 
                                               userAssertion);
 }
}
```

Supposedly `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` attempts to retrieve a token without user interaction, while `AcquireTokenAsync` prompts the user for permission.  However...This function is being called within a Web API that's trying to call another Web API - so there's no way to prompt the user for permission at all.  Which one do I use?  Do I need to use both?

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you just use the second (with userAssertion) since that's all you have in a WebAPI - the incoming token of a user of the client calling you. Note that this API will NOT prompt the user - that a different signature with PlatfromParameters. This API will exchange an incoming token addressed to this API for a token addressed to the API this one needs to call.

Comment: OK that's good to know - so I can use `AquireTokenAsync` by itself and `AuthenticationContext` will still look use the token in the cache if it exists?

Comment: You can check my article on the topic: https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-on-behalf-of-aspnet-core It should return a token from cache if available